# AFNetworking return in function

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I use `AFNetworking` framework https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.
All well but the function returns `Null`, but everything is fine `NSLog` returns `Null`.
What could be the reason?

```
-(NSString *)cook
{
    __block NSString *fecho =nil;

    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"];

    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];

    [httpClient defaultValueForHeader:@"Accept"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET"  path:@"" parameters:nil];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    [httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
    {
        fecho = [[operation.response allHeaderFields] valueForKeyPath:@"Date"];

        NSLog(@"%@",fecho);
    }
                                     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
    {
         fecho = @"errr";
    }];

    [request setTimeoutInterval:20.0];
    [operation start];

    return fecho;
}
```

big thank!

Comment: `fecho` will assigned with value only after completion of operation, either success or failure. And here `fecho` returns before completion of operation.

Comment: `Google.com` doesn't have anything for key `Date`

Comment: Akhilrajtr, how to wait and run?

Comment: You can not wait you have to divide your task in two part before network request and after network request. for after network request make method like this - (void) preformaAfterResponse:(NSString *)fecho; and call this method from setCompletionBlockWithSuccess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `-(NSString *)cook` to

```
- (void)cookOnCompletion:(void (^)(NSString *errorMessage))completion {

     NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"];

     AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];

     [httpClient defaultValueForHeader:@"Accept"];

     NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET"  path:@"" parameters:nil];

     AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    [httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
    {
        NSString *fecho = [[operation.response allHeaderFields] valueForKeyPath:@"Date"];

        completion(fecho);
    }
                                 failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
    {
         NSString *error = @"errr";
         completion(error);
    }];

    [request setTimeoutInterval:20.0];
    [operation start];
}
```

and call `cookOnCompletion:` like

```
[self cookOnCompletion:^(NSString *response){
    NSLog(@"%@",response);
}];
```